# Symfony 2. How I can set default values to embedded forms from entities?

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, default-value

I need to set default values for my form. There is code, from my controller:

```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('user', new Form\UserType($user))
                                    ->add('client', new Form\ClientType($client))
                                    ->getForm();
```

And I have two entites: User & Client. So, how I can set default values from entites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the default values for my text fields like this

```
->add('firstname', 'text', array('attr' => array('value' => 'bla')))
```

for an Entity you can set empty value to false and fill the prefrred_choices array

```
->add('language', 'entity', array('empty_value' => false, 'preferred_choices' => array('2'), 'class' => 'CPAppUserBundle:Language', ))
```

Answer (score -2):

In the form classes of each your user and your client class you can set default values like this:

```
public function configure() {
  $this->setDefault('yourfield', $defaultvalue);
}
```

Comment: Not working on Symfony2. This seems to be Symfony 1.x related.